# Java - cancel queued calls on synchronized functions

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm just getting started with Threads in Java so this might be a basic question, but I couldn't find the answer online.

I have two threads that can call one synchronized function. The way I understand it, if the second thread calls it while the first thread has already called it, the second thread will wait until the first thread is done before calling it. However, I don't want the second thread  to call it at all.

Comment: What is your difficulty here?  Why not design the second thread so it doesn't call that method?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much the case. Do you mean that if a method has been called once, you don't want to allow to be called again? Like "dirty" flag?

Comment: I wanted something like the lock in JB Nizet's answer. Again, I'm new to working with multiple threads, I didn't know about them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then the easiest way is to use an explicit lock ([`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)) and call its `tryLock()` method.

If it returns true, then it means that no other thread has the lock, and the current thread acquired it.

If it returns false, it means that another thread holds the lock, and you should not call the method.

Remember to always call `unlock()` in a finally block, to make sure the lock is released even in case an exception is thrown.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. I'll accept after I run a few tests later.